# FIX transport logon message, username/password configuration

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, apache-synapse

In the FIX transport implementation, If synapse acts as an initiator, it first sends logon message to the acceptor..If the acceptor requires username/password for logon message, is there a way to provide that configuration in initiator.cfg file?

In the logon message  it has two tags for username and password. So, acceptor might require these fields for logon purpose.

Comment: i am also faceing same problem .. Providing user name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add fields to the cfg file if you wish but quickfix will not automatically read them and put them into the logon message as it does with things like TargetCompID.  The result is you need to read them and add them in toAdmin.

Personally I have another config file anyway so I add usernames and password to that and add them to the message in toAdmin.

Comment: can you give me a sample >>

Comment: have a look in the sample cfg file